# Use Python to get link from a form with authenticity token

Tags: php, python, forms-authentication

I am wondering if it's possible to make a script in Python that parses the authencity token from a fom and get its correspondent link. 
What would be the best approach to do so?

I am attaching a piece of the HTML source code as reference.

```
<form id="take_file_form"  class="edit_document ng-pristine no-valid" data-dynamic-pricing-activated="true"  data-dynamic-pricing-url="https://
api.textmaster.com/privateldocuments/Sd9208496831676601735397/
dynamic _pricing- data-dynamic-pricing.refresh-interval-in-sec="128"
action="/authors/tasksJ5d920849683I6700e1735397/start"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden"  value="✓">
<input type="hidden"  name="_method" value="patch">
<input type="hidden"  name="authenticity_token" value="Sall2FcgxufyNBTFw4sUlliallY09+EljvfKEFdgzijsullgv+2Q811aggs7BovNytlFShGxjincdOrga78==">                                                                                                                                                                                                             <input id="document_dynamic_author_word_count" type="hidden" name="document[dynamic_author_word_count]" value="8">                                                                                         <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Pegue essa tarefa" class=
"anim btn blue-hg action-btn"> == $0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post code as a screenshot, instead use properly formatted text

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).